# The animal with the fastest hair growing rate

Tags: growth, hair

we know that human hair usually grows about 1/2 inch a month.
My question is what is the species with the fastest hair growing rate? (including fur for example).

Comment: Welcome! What did you find when you googled this? You need to make/show us an attempt to answer this. (Hover over the down vote arrow.) Many people take offense when informed that they need to show their attempt to answer this question first. Isn't this a Q&A site? Yes, but it's an "advanced" Q&A site, so to speak. This requirement is puzzling to many, but it is not personal or meant to make you feel "less than". We do (often gladly) answer even basic questions that show research. Every site has a culture. This is ours; we're not trying to be unwelcoming. Please edit to include what you found.

Comment: I'd love to be able to give some info on that topic, unfortunately it's an overlooked field of science. I found that hair growth speed depends on the area of the body and is regulated by cortisol, and that Asians have faster growing hair than Africans.